# How to access the alias name in below query

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

Below is my query, I want to access the UNQKEY value I can use it in order by but I want to use it in where condition. Is there any want to use the UNQKEY as part of where condition?

```
SELECT distinct TOCID,'UNQKEY' || r UNQKEY  ,TOCNAME,
  decode( r, 1, UNQKEY1, 2, UNQKEY2, 3, UNQKEY3, 4, UNQKEY4 ,   5, UNQKEY5) AS 
  UNQKEY_VALUE
FROM TOC, RULE RL,
  (select rownum r
    from all_objects
    where rownum <=5) 
WHERE TOCID=1210 
ORDER BY UNQKEY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use it in a `where` clause, then use a subquery or CTE:

```
select *
from (select distinct TOCID, 'UNQKEY' || r as UNQKEY , TOCNAME,
             decode( r, 1, UNQKEY1, 2, UNQKEY2, 3, UNQKEY3, 4, UNQKEY4 ,   5, UNQKEY5) AS UNQKEY_VALUE
      from TOC, RULE RL,
           (select rownum r
            from all_objects
            where rownum <=5
           )
      ) t
WHERE TOCID = 1210 and UNQKEY like '%%'
order by UNQKEY;
```

Comment: FYI, you have the word, "here", where you intend to have the word, "where".

Comment: I need to use this query in update statement

UPDATE RUN_RESULT SET UNQKEY =
(
select UNQKEY_VALUE from (
select distinct RUN_ID,TOCID, 'UNQKEY' || r as UNQKEY , TOCNAME,UNIQUENESS_COLUMN_ID,
DECODE( r, 1, UNQKEY1, 2, UNQKEY2, 3, UNQKEY3, 4, UNQKEY4 ,   5, UNQKEY5) AS UNQKEY_VALUE
from TOC TOC, 
RULE RL,
RUN_RESULT RR,
(select rownum r from all_objects where rownum <=5)
WHERE RL.RULE_SET_ID=RR.RULE_SET_ID  
AND TOC.TOCID= RR.TOC_ID
) t
WHERE UNIQUENESS_COLUMN_ID like UNQKEY
 
and UNQKEY_VALUE IS NOT NULL

) Where ?????

I have to use the inner query column, how to access in the outer query

Comment: @Jey . . . I would suggest that you ask another question.